# How to enable a command only when the selected element has certain property?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm building am eclipse plugin and I have a tree representation where I display the structure of an element of type A(see below).

```
Class A{
  List<B> children;
}

Abstract Class B{
  ...
}

Class C extend B{
  ...
}

Class D extend B{
  ...
}
```

I have a command which can start only when the selected element in the three is an instance of A.
This is the expression I'm using.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
  <definition id="SelectionOfA">
    <with variable="selection">
      <and>
        <count value="1"></count>
        <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
          <instanceof value="A"></instanceof>
        </iterate>
      </and>
    </with>
  </definition>
</extension>
```

Now I would like to refine this condition. I would like to enable the command only when an instance of A is selected and the list children contains at least an element which is instance of C.
I tried by keeping this expression and defining a new one. Then I will enable the command only if both the expressions are true. I started from the expression reported above and I tried to replace the tag `instanceof` with the tags `with`, `iterate` and `adapt` without a good result.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement a **property tester** to check if the condition is met.

Something like this should do the work:

```
public class YourConditionTester extends PropertyTester {
  public boolean test(final Object receiver, final String property, final Object[] args, final Object expectedValue) {
    if (property.equals("isA_and_hasC")) {
      return (true if your condition is met, otherwise false)
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then, instead of `instanceof` use `test` with `property` set (e.g.) to "isA_and_hasC".

Look [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_expressions_propertyTesters.html) for more info about property testers.

Comment: It is working. However I had to set the attribute `forcepluginactivation` of `test` to true. Is it correct? And also, I see that the expressions is continuously evaluated also if I don't change the focus. It is possible to evaluate it only once?

Comment: The attribute `forcepluginactivation` tells Eclipse that it should load the plugin in the case it's not yet loaded AND some feature implemented in this plugin is used in plugin.xml (even from a different plugin). So yes, if you want to be sure that this tester will be used if needed, set it to *true*. As for unnecessary calls, that's something I find to be very common for Eclipse UI a AFAIK there's not much to do about it. It's definitely reasonable to keep property tester code as lightweight as possible.